# EasyCap video grabber - no colors

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-capture

I have a Syntek [EasyCap STK1160](http://easycapexpertti.mybisi.com/product/easycap-dc60-v21c-usb-20-video-capture-xp-vista) video capture card and a wireless camera with colors. I've connected the receiver to the PC with the video capture card and I use VLC to view it (directshow). I'm getting the video with a little delay but no colors. How can I get the colors?

Comment: Please provide a link to the product's information.

Comment: http://easycapexpertti.mybisi.com/product/easycap-dc60-v21c-usb-20-video-capture-xp-vista

Comment: most likely NTSC / PAL(SECAM) settings either on the USB capture card or on the Camera. More the latter.